# Java AWS Lambda error loading class

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I am quite new to Amazon Web Services. I created a lambda function but when I run it from Amazon console I get the following error:

> Error loading class com.aws.codestar.projecttemplates.handler.UserHandler: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB: class java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/AmazonDynamoDB
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
>       Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>           ... 2 more

How to resolve the problem?

This is the list of dependencies that I'm using in my project:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.106</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

Comment: You're getting this error because you're not imported the correct lib for your project. Please provide to us what lib did you import to your project or the maven pom (if you use maven). You also can reference [here](http://snacktrace.com/artifacts/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.10.1/com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB) for the same missing

Comment: @TuyenNguyen what dependency is missing? this is my pom.xml

Comment: Do you need dynamoDB (or events)? I have deployed a RequestStreamHandler to AWS lambda with just the core.

Comment: You might try to import `com.amazonaws` by normal way with `version` included instead of using `dependencyManagement`

Comment: @TuyenNguyen same problem :(